# How can I remove an extension for an Azure scale set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I know I can remove extensions for Azure Virtual machines, however how can I do the same for an Azure Scale Set deployed with RM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Azure CLI 2.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) to remove VMSS's extensions. You could use the following command.

```
az vmss extension delete --name
                         --resource-group
                         --vmss-name
```

I test in my lab, you could refer to the following examples.

1.List VMSS extesnion.

```
root@shui:~/.ssh# az vmss extension list --resource-group shuivmss --vmss-name shui
[
  {
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "id": null,
    "name": "customScript",
    "protectedSettings": null,
    "provisioningState": null,
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": [
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-vmss-custom-script-windows/scripts/helloWorld.ps1"
      ]
    },
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8"
  }
]
```

2.Get extension name and remove it.

```
az vmss extension delete --name customScript --resource-group shuivmss --vmss-name shui
```

More information about `az vmss extension` usage please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss/extension).

Comment: @guillem Sorry for my mistake, Azure Cli 2.0 installer link is wrong. I updated it. Does it work?

Comment: already had it installed so didn't notice it. Very handy you also provided me the option to list the extension. I removed it easily.

Comment: In my case I was removing the docker extension on linux machines and I had to set instances to 0 and then recreate then as reimaging was not enough to really delete the extension content. A bit tricky but it worked after all

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that using the `Remove-AzureRmVmssExtension` Powershell cmdlet is the easiest way. I was unable to find any real examples, but I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be very hard.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/remove-azurermvmssextension?view=azurermps-4.0.0

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this one! Will try and come back with feedback.

Comment: I finally removed it with az cli but I assume this will work with PS